# bidirectional many to one with no FK between tables

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one

I am trying to adding Many to one relation into Table `A` since `A` will need to able to get `B`'s columns every time user post/put/get/etc into Table `A` with updatable `name`.

If `A` create with `id = "aaa"` and `name = "a_name"`, it should get the columns with same `id` and `name` from Table `B`. If `A` update with `id = "aaa"` and `name = "b_name"`, it does the same thing.

The problem is that there is no fk or other relation between two tables even if hibernate doesn't care about constraint.

Any idea to fix this?

```
Table A
id (PK) vachar
name vachar
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

```
Table B
id (PK) vachar
nm (PK) vachar
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Code:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  @JoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "nm")
  public B b;
}
```

it works if I put `insertable = false` and `updatable = false`, but that doesn't meet the requirement since Table `A` should able to update the name.

```
public class B implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  String id;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "nm")
  String name;
}
```

Comment: it looks like an incorrectly implemented relation. [It might be usefull](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Any other approach to the solution. I have been looking of the solution for a while.